# Why did Tolkien reverse the more common traditional genders assigned to the sun and moon?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, j-r-r-tolkien, tolkiens-legendarium

In most cultures throughout history, from ancient Rome to China, from the Americas to Africa, there has been a general trend (although there have been plenty of exceptions) in assigning a gender to the sun and moon.  Especially in cultures most familiar to Westerners, the [sun is usually male](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_deity), and [the moon is usually female](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lunar_deities).  For instance, the sun is associated with male deities such as Ra, Horus, Apollo, etc, and the name itself- Sol - is masculine;  the moon is generally associated with goddesses, and the name is explicitly feminine- Luna.  I am not sure why the sun is usually conceived of as male, but the belief that the moon is feminine apparently stems from the perceived connection between moon cycles and menstruation.

In Lord of the Rings, however, people (and Elves, and Dwarves, and Hobbits) consistently refer to the sun as "she" or "her", and to the moon as "he" or "him".  I doubt that Tolkien was making a statement about gender equality, but **I haven't the foggiest idea as to why he chose to reverse the most common traditional gender assignments for the sun and moon.  Does he say anything about this in his writing?**

Comment: Tolkien in the Lord of the Rings took a lot of inspiration from his work on philology in the Germanic languages, specifically Old English. In Old English, *sunne* is a feminine noun and *mōna* is a masculine noun. So in fact, there is no reversal: Tolkien is using the more traditional Germanic gender for the sun and moon.  I would guess that this is the reason he assigns them these genders in the Silmarillion. It is (some) modern English speakers that have reversed gender associations with the sun and moon, probably under the influence of Romance languages and Greek and Latin mythology.

Comment: Your initial presupposition is also fairly arguable. See this section of your linked article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_deity#Male_and_female

Comment: @sumelic Please write this as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: I didn't because the bolded part of the question asks for sources from Tolkien's writings specifically. If the questioner indicates that outside explanations are also acceptable, though, I could  turn it into an answer.

Comment: @sumelic - you have my permission, but you never really needed it.  "He didn't reverse anything, and your question makes assumptions that don't hold up, dummy!" is a valid answer, and seems to be the truth as well.  :)

Comment: To note, in Shinto Amaterasu is the Sun Goddess and her bother Tsukuyomi is the Moon God and there is alot of anime (that i've seen) which uses Shinto concepts so far more often than not the Sun is female while the Moon is male if you mainly watch anime over anything else

Comment: As a German I live in middle Europe and our languages love to place articles to nouns. For the languages I know the sun is female (German "Die Sonne") and the moon is male (German "Der Mond"). As Tolkien heavily based his universe on European mythology, he may just have been used to these languages. //EDIT: Note to myself, read answers before wisenheimering (in German you say "Klugscheißer", what translates to "pooping wisely")

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It seems that in germanic languages, notably German, the sun/moon genders are "reversed" like that, as sumelic commented.

Die Sonne (sun, female)
Der Mond (moon, male)

In other words, your assumption that male sun / female moon is somehow "general rule" doesn't hold up. And you don't even need to look at some exotic place.

Comment: your answer seems logically perfect as it is a verified fact that Tolkien's writings were influenced by Germanic mythologies.

Comment: Further, in Norse mythology (which, as already stated, influenced Tolkien a lot), the deity that is associated with the moon is male (Máni) and the one of the sun is female (Sól). See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Máni)

Comment: After all, there is a Man in the Moon :-).

Comment: A man, and lest we forget, [a rabbit](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_rabbit)

Comment: @FrancisDavey As far as innuendos go, that sentence can go both ways. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: This is probably the most correct answer, although I might add that Tolkien is ostensibly translating a work of "Westron" into English, and he decided that "Westron" would have an Anglo-Saxon influence

Comment: Well done.  I was one of the English speakers wiki mentioned as assuming that the sun is usually make and the moon is usually female.

Comment: Not related to Tolkien, but as an example, Arabic and Persian both are exceptions to this "rule"

Comment: Baltic and Finno-Ugric pre-medieval traditions also had Sun as female and Moon as male; I wouldn't be surprised if that's the way it had been since the original proto-indoeuropean roots.

Comment: As an example Czech (and some other slavic languages, like Russian), have Sun as neuter and Moon male.

Answer (score 13):

Another point to this (and maybe the cause why people of Middle-Earth refer to sun and moon in this way) is that in Middle-Earth mythology, the sun (which is a fruit of Laurelin, the golden tree) is guided through the sky by Arien (a female maia) and the moon (a fruit of Telperion, the silver tree) by Tilion (a male maia).

This is described in The Silmarillion (or in summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_Moon_%28Middle-earth%29) on Wikipedia).

Comment: This is an in-universe answer, while the question appears to be asking for an out-of-universe answer.

Comment: And also probably Tolkien choose these Maïar genders to be aligned with the germanic tradition and explain it at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

As already answered, there are indeed cultures that have personified the sun and moon as female and male, respectively, and languages that have given them female and male names, respectively.

To be a bit more specific than the answer already given, the language that Tolkien would have been thinking of most when deciding how Westron worked (the language that is always "translated" into English) is Anglo-Saxon.

In Anglo-Saxon, *sunne* (from which the Modern English word *sun* is derived) is feminine, and *mona* (from which the Modern English word *moon* is derived) is masculine.

In keeping with Tolkien's idea that the LOTR should be an alternative folklore for the English-speaking peoples, and in his general use of language (e.g. calling the world "Middle Earth", as the Angles and Saxons did), he has Westron being a predecessor of English, and so feminine *sun* and masculine *moon* is the obvious choice.